# Ionic2 hooks ionViewWillLeave and ionViewWillEnter communication

Tags: ionic2

In an Ionic2 application, I have 2 pages, one transitions to the other, so I have a ionViewWillLeave in the first one and ionViewWillEnter in the second one.

```
SourcePage {
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    // updating some info with http calls for this page
  }
}

NextPage {
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    // reading some info with http calls for this page
  }
}
```

I want to finish some sync tasks in the first page before leaving and I want those tasks to finish before the tasks in the next page are executed.

Is there a way to do this? Like, do I need to use a service to communicate between them or there's an easier way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yeah sounds about right, I would create a service `sharedService` and set up a flag when the first page is done processing, the second page can read the flag and act accordingly. You can also try following:

`withinfirstPage-->someHttpCall.then((result)=>{
    //processing done
    navCtrl.push(secondPage)
    });`